# How to set up a Windows Scheduled Task to delete a specific file every 2 weeks?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I need to delete a specific file every 2 weeks. The file is:
C:\Logfile.txt

I thought I could use Windows Task Sceduler to do this, but there seems to be no option to create a 'Delete File' task.

Can someone help with this please?

Cheers for all help

Comment: Start deletion as a command: `cmd /c del C:\Logfile.txt`. Or start any script/program which performed this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @[Akina](https://superuser.com/users/910710/akina)'s comment states, you'll either want to use the `del` command directly:

```
cmd /c del /f /q "C:\Logfile.txt"
```

or via a batch file your scheduled task would point to:

```
@echo off

del /f /q "C:\Logfile.txt"

exit
```

Either way, I would likely include the `/f` to ignore the read-only attribute and the `/q` avoid a confirmation prompt - this way nothing should hang the task up.